# Remove double quotes around value

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, double, quotes

Python noob, used to much lower level languages..
I am working with an app that saves json into csv and vice-versus.  The LOCATION object below has double quotes around the single quotes of the "{ 'coordinates'.  I've tried to strip it various ways, re.sub, replace, etc.  There would be many thousands of these lines in a file.  When I use json.dumps or json.loads from the dict, I end up with an illegal json file or at least one that does not work in my application.

[OrderedDict([('`GROUP`', '`Net-10-172-192`'), ('`NAME`', '`IOT`'), ('`CIDR`', '`192.168.69.0/24`'), ('`DESCRIPTION`', '``'), ('`DOMAIN`', '`Default Domain`'), ('`LOCATION`', "`{'coordinates': [-80.25572"), ('`COUNTRY_CODE`', ' 37.11923]'), (None, [" 'type': 'Point'}`", '`US`'])])]

Comment: you do a json.dumps on the below data ?

[OrderedDict([('GROUP', 'Net-10-172-192'), ('NAME', 'IOT'), ('CIDR', '192.168.69.0/24'), ('DESCRIPTION', '``'), ('DOMAIN', 'Default Domain'), ('LOCATION', "{'coordinates': [-80.25572"), ('COUNTRY_CODE', ' 37.11923]'), (None, [" 'type': 'Point'}", 'US'])])]

Comment: Yes, it returned the below. I added the first and last set of quotes.  Notice the LOCATION": "then a curly brace.  That is what the engine I'm submitting the json too will not accept. 
 "{"GROUP": "Net-10-172-192", "NAME": "IOT", "CIDR": "192.168.69.0/24", "DESCRIPTION": "``", "DOMAIN": "Default Domain", "LOCATION": "{'coordinates': [-80.25572", "COUNTRY_CODE": " 37.11923]", "null": [" 'type': 'Point'}", "US"]}"